# Can I use react and babel without webpack? Or do I need all 3 in combination?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, babeljs

So I was able to create my own environment for react using webpack and babel, however, when I try to replicate what I did with just react and webpack I get syntax errors in the transpired code for the reactjs file.

For example the "require react" statement in the transpiled file fails. Any ideas why this might occur? Is it not possible to create a react environment with only Babel and not webpack?

Thanks in advance for any answers!

EDIT: Below is my setup with just Babel

[image: Folder structure]

babel.config.js file

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);

  const presets = ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"];


  return {
    presets
  };
}
```

reactTest.js file below

```
var React = require('react')
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom')



class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>test!</div>
            )
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

package.json below

```
{
  "name": "webpack-babel-learning",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "babel src -d lib"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0"
  }
}
```

Let me know if you need anything else. Sorry for late reply was making dinner.

Comment: Of course it is, Babel and Webpack are two completely separate librarys doing completely different things. Show your setup i.e. Babel config, target node version etc

Comment: While possible, it can make it hard to follow along with examples. But it can be done. You can't use JSX syntax and some other niceties though.

Comment: @GarrettMotzner you can't use JSX syntax without Webpack? I _highly_ doubt that.

Comment: whoops, I meant babel. :)

Comment: However, I am confused now, @noobcoderiam. What component are you trying to remove? Webpack, or babel? Because your description and title seem to disagree.

Comment: Take a look at this for some alternatives, and what the different types of build tools do: https://survivejs.com/webpack/appendices/comparison/#bundlers

Comment: i added source code

Comment: @James i added source code

Comment: @GarrettMotzner TRYING to remove webpack just so i can understand babel better

Comment: Ok. Got it. Also, please sensor your code samples for profanity. :)

Comment: @GarrettMotzner done

Comment: You *can*, if your willing to do a great deal of work. But the syntax that React uses for imports is webpacks and is subtly incompatible with e.g. native modules.

Comment: @JaredSmith that's all I needed to hear. I'm just trying to understand react as best as possible from the bottom up.

Comment: @noobcoderiam - all React is doing with JSX is providing syntactic sugar for this: `return React.createElement('h1', null, 'Greetings, ' + this.props.name + '!');`.From this article: https://medium.com/@chrislewisdev/react-without-npm-babel-or-webpack-1e9a6049714

Comment: @jaredgorski the problem isn't JSX, there's plenty of JSX transformers. The problem is the module system.

Comment: Totally. I just added that because he’s interested in understanding React and it’s a cool article.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. Just choose another bundler.

**Parcel** – zero configurable bundler for both web & node

**Rollup** –  bundler for NodeJS code mostly

**Microbundle** –  bundler for tiny modules based on Rollup

**Browserify** – `require` in a browser

Comment: Have you actually tried to do that with another module bundler?

Comment: @JaredSmith yes I did. I wouldn't write anything here if I didn't try them

Comment: No, I mean tried to use *React* with another bundler. It's pretty webpack-oriented.

Comment: @JaredSmith I use Parcel in my almost all projects cos' it is simpler to setup than webpack

Comment: Your answer would be greatly improved by a brief description of how to do so, preferably with code examples.

Comment: @JaredSmith I can't add any code to Parcel because it is zero configurable and also it is CLI. The same with Microbundle

Answer (score 0):

You probably can, though it might not be as ideal for production as bundling with Webpack (or some other build tool) because you'll be doing the transpilation client-side rather than server-side, which could slow things down a lot.

If you want to use Babel without a build process, you have to accept that you'll be doing all of your transpilation client-side. The build process (also known as bundle process) is what allows you to render everything "server side" (on your computer or host server) before sending your code to the client (the browser). [Here's a helpful article on developing without a bundler.](https://medium.com/chialab-open-source/a-study-about-how-to-improve-frontend-dev-experience-without-a-bundler-1b4c3a461a35) Without transpilation, the browser can't run your code because it only runs a certain flavor of JavaScript natively (currently a basic form of ES5 or, to be safe, commonJS).

The Babel documentation for **[@babel/standalone](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-standalone.html)** states that you can run Babel in the browser, apparently by including `type="text/babel"` in the `<script>` tag you're using to import your React component to the HTML it's appending.

```
// Load Babel.
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

// Load your React component with type set to "text/babel".
<script src="my_component.js" type="text/babel"></script>
```

From the **[@babel/standalone](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-standalone.html)** docs: `Note that config files don't work in @babel/standalone, as no file system access is available. The presets and/or plugins to use must be specified in the options passed to Babel.transform.`

^^What this means is that you'll have to run your code through the `Babel.transform()` method like so:

```
var myCode = 'const getMessage = () => "Hello World";';
var output = Babel.transform(myCode, { presets: ['es2015'] }).code;
```

This appears to be saying that you need to wrap all of your JS code in quotes (to make it a giant string) and then pass that string to the `Babel.transform()` method, which takes two parameters: 1) your code, and 2) your babel configuration. This looks like a pain compared to just using a bundler, if you ask me.

This also means that you don't need to include Babel in your npm devDependencies, since it won't be running in your node environment but rather in the client. So, congratulations on removing some node modules!

Anyway, according to the [documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-standalone.html), it seems like this should work if you want to do things this way.

Comment: So is what you are saying that without webpack, you need to manually load files from urls?

Comment: Why would transpilation client side be a security concern?

Comment: Ah, good point. I imagine Babel will be just fine if you import React in the JS file. I'll update my answer for clarity.

Comment: correct.  but would definitely not advise it, since you'll be doing a build each time a user loads the page.  your load time will be drastically affected

Comment: And transpilation client-side wouldn't be a security concern (that I know of), I was more referring to rendering React client-side just in case OP was using React for any dynamic stuff or server connections.

Comment: Sweet. I just updated my answer with some details on using Babel client-side (e.g., "why is it client-side", "what is client-side", "what difference does it make", "how does this affect my tooling and development setup", etc.)